# If the three vectors are co-planar, then what is the value of $a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Question:**

What should be the value of $a$ so that the three vectors $2\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}$, $3\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+4\hat{k}$ and $\hat{i}-3\hat{j}+a\hat{k}$ are coplanar?

(a) 5

(b) 7

(c) 4

(d) 3

**My attempt:**

Using the [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product), I found that a=5. So, (a) is correct.

**My instructor's attempt:**

$$\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 & -1\\
3 & -2 & 4\\
1 & -3 & a
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

And then they solved for a. They also found that a=5. So, (a) is correct.

**My question:**

1. I've never seen the problem done in the way my instructor did. I always have done this type of problem using the scalar triple product. Where does my instructor's attempt originate from? What are the differences between my attempt and my instructor's attempt, if any?
2. Using the scalar triple product, we get the volume enclosed by the three vectors. If the volume is zero, we conclude that the vectors are co-planar. Can the volume enclosed by the vectors be found using my instructor's process?

Comment: The scalar triple product can be calculated by the determinant in your link: look at the fourth bullet point under "properties": "The scalar triple product can also be understood as the determinant of the 3×3 matrix".

Comment: @user1046533 Right! I totally missed it. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scalar triple product can be calculated by the determinant in your link: look at the fourth bullet point under "properties":

> "The scalar triple product can also be understood as the determinant of the 3×3 matrix".